# adding alert when its crossingup/Down on interactive trendline(Pinescript)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

i cant figure out how to call the line to make Conditions when X is crossingup/Down to the Line. thankyou in advance

```
a = input.price(0,'a', inline=  '1', confirm=true)
b = input.time(0,'b', inline=  '1', confirm=true)
c = input.price(0,'c', inline=  '2', confirm=true)
d = input.time(0,'d', inline=  '2', confirm=true)

if barstate.islast
aa =line.new(x1=b, y1=a,x2=d, y2=c,xloc=xloc.bar_time,color=color.lime,
     width=2, style=line.style_solid,
     extend=extend.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `y` value of the line with the `line.get_y2()` function.

Then use `ta.crossover()` or `ta.crossunder()` with that value.

```
_y2 = line.get_y2(aa)

co = ta.crossover(close, _y2)
cu = ta.crossunder(close, _y2)

alertcondition(co, "Crossing up")
alertcondition(cu, "Crossing down")
```

Comment: but y2 = C which is referring to a PRICE, only if the Close is crossing to the certain Price Level but not the Trendline itself.